# Most efficient implementation to get the closest k items

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, asymptotic-complexity

In the K-Nearest-Neighbor algorithm, we find the top k neighbors closest to a new point out of N observations and use those neighbors to classify the point.  From my knowledge of data structures, I can think of two implementations of this process:

Approach 1

1. Calculate the distances to the new point from each of N observations
2. Sort the distances using quicksort and take the top k points

Which would take O(N + NlogN) = O(NlogN) time.

Approach 2

1. Create a max-heap of size k
2. Calculate the distance from the new point for the first k points
3. For each following observation, if the distance is less than the max in the heap, pop that point from the heap and replace it with the current observation
4. Re-heapify (logk operations for N points)
5. Continue until there are no more observations at which point we should only have the top 5 closest distances in the heap.

This approach would take O(N + NlogK) = O(NlogK) operations.

Are my analyses correct?  How would this process be optimized in a standard package like sklearn?  Thank you!

Comment: Your analysis is right. But have you got any proximity information to avoid full range looping? Like kd-trees or another spatial data structures.

Comment: I haven't encountered kd-trees before; what kind of info would that be and how can it be leveraged to improve runtime?

Comment: Not kdtrees just example: Imagine chessboard and points on it. To find neighbors for point in E4 cell, at first check points belonging to the same cell, then points in the closest cells: E5,D4,F4,E3, then D5,F5,D3,E3, Note that you have to examine only 9 from 64 cells (if they contains enough points). And more andvanced data structures migt answer to query: return M closest points with complexity like `O(MlogN)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good overview of the common methods used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

What you describe is linear search (since you need to compute the distance to every point in the dataset).
The good thing is that this always works. The bad thing about it is that is slow, especially if you query it a lot.

If you know a bit more about your data you can get better performance. If the data has low dimensionality (2D, 3D) and is  uniformly distributed (this doesn't mean perfectly, just not in very dense and very tight clusters) then space partitioning works great because it cuts down quickly on the points that are too far anyway (complexity O(logN) ). They work also for higher dimensionallity or if there are some clusters, but the performance suffers a bit (still better overall than linear search).

Usually space partitioning or locality sensitive hashing are enough for common datasets.

The trade-off is that you use more memory and some set-up time to speed up future queries. If you have a lot of queries then it's worth it. If you only have a few, not so much.